# Display images in a row (HTML)

Tags: html, image, row

So I have this very simple HTML page. All I want is to display images in one long row. What is the simplest way, that would work on all browsers?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My title</title>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="images">
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="2.jpg">
<img src="3.jpg">
<img src="4.jpg">
<img src="5.jpg">
<img src="6.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want `#images` to be a single row, you can turn off [word wrapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```
#images {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs3rY/)**

Answer (score 6):

Look this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/EhANEDe/1/edit)

I think this is the simplest way:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="4.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="6.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

Updated: For no wrap!

Answer (score 0):

Make your container `div` wide enough to handle all of your images.

Let's say all your images are 300px by 300px;. if you have 6 images, your div would be 1800px wide

Just make the container div wide enough to accommodate all of your images and they won't wrap. Then float each image left.

```
<style>
    #images  {
        width: 1800px;
        height: 300px;
    }
    #images img {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

I'm suspecting somebody with much more CSS knowledge will have a better way?...

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
      <img src="1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="column">
      <img src="2.jpg">
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

See [How To Place Images Side by Side](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_images_side_by_side.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/gEGMF/)

```
#images {
  width: 2000px; /* Increase if needed */
}
#images img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```